# how to current language used in tvml application using tvjs for localisation

Tags: localization, localizable.strings, tvml, tvjs, tvos11

Im a beginner in tvOS application . Im using tvml  and tvjs. I want to do localisation in my application. How will I get the current language used and interface language used in application.

Comment: ATV.settings.language

Answer (score 0):

Use `Settings.language`.

Also check out: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmljs/settings